# i'm getting a syntax error not sure why? when calling .evaluate display sidebar data from google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

1. function onOpen() {   var ss =
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
         menuItems = [{name: "displaybar", functionName: "displayDataAsSidebar"}];   ss.addMenu("sidebar", menuItems); }

   function addRows() {   var ss =
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
         sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
         rows = [['Number','First Name',
                  'Last Name','Points'],
                 [00, 'Eve','Jackson',94],
                 [01,'John','Doe',80],
                 [02,'Adam','Johnson',67],
                 [03,'Jill','Smith',50]],
         rng,
         rngName = 'Input';   rows.forEach(function(row){
       sheet.appendRow(row);   });   rng = sheet.getDataRange();   ss.setNamedRange(rngName,rng); } function displayDataAsSidebar() {
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dummy Data');
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()   .showSidebar(html.evaluate())}

   function getData(){   var ss =
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
         rng = ss.getRangeByName('Input'),
         data = rng.getValues();   return data; }

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>


<style>
  table {
    border-collapse:
    collapse;
    }
    td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    
    <div> <h1>Dummy Data</h1>
    <? =var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
    <?= for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {?>
    <tr>
    <?= for(var j = 0;j <data[i].length;j++) { ?>
    <td> <? = var data[i][j] ?> 
    </td> <? } ?>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scriptlet syntax is wrong. <?= ?> prints to the page while <? ?> is used for writing inline JavaScript. Eval() breaks because it actually attempts to execute the code after the '=' sign and output the result to the page.

```
 <?= for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {?>
```

Solution is to remove '=' from 'for' loops. Although your code for writing to the cell is correct, there's no need to include 'var' in it.

```
<? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
    <? for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {?>
    <tr>
    <? for(var j = 0;j <data[i].length;j++) { ?>
    <td> <?= data[i][j] ?> 
    </td> <? } ?>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution i have tried as you suggested removing '=' from 'for' loops.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate()) is now highlighted with a syntax error "Code"

Comment: i have removed all '=' and get this message SyntaxError: Missing ; after for-loop initialiser. (line 25, file "Code")

Comment: That's likely due to the extra space in this line <?= data[i][j] ?>  . I removed the space between '?' and '=' and it worked

Comment: Excellent! ,Thanks very much! have a  great day!